# What MCU-type hardware is needed to read 12-110MHz pixel data from a video decoder?

Tags: arm, parallel, video, decoder, scaling

The goal is to display PAL/NTSC (576i/480i) video on 32x16 RGB LED matrix. Scaling down the video is thus needed. From that point it is fairly easy – 32x16 image used to drive the matrix.

I have chosen 80 MHz ARM Cortex controller from Texas Instruments – Tiva C 123GXL. Block diagram looks like the following:

[image]

ADV7181C is Analog Devices video decoder. It allows very flexible outputs:

[image]

There is `LLC` pin with clock of the pixel port, `12`-`110` `MHz`. Is the 80-MHz ARM Cortex enough to somehow read video frames at say `10`-`20` FPS? One idea is to connect `LLC` as interrupt to the MCU. I assume that `LLC` will be at `~60` `MHz` max for PAL/NTSC input. Can I connect at that frequency? What about `110` `MHz`, maximum `LLC`, what do I need (which other MCU) to read and down-scale the frames in such situation?

I'm not sure if the Tiva allows some kind of parallel bus. There is uDMA: "ARM® PrimeCell® 32-channel configurable μDMA controller". But I also need to down-scale online, because of 32 kB SRAM memory available. Maybe this is on-topic: "PCF8575C, Remote 16-bit I/O expander for I2C-bus"?

MCU features: imgur.com/a/jHxOJ

MCU datasheet: www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu296/spmu296.pdf

ADV7181C datasheet: www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/041/ADV7181C-pdf.php

Comment: You'd be better off using a small FPGA than trying to find a way to make the MCU grab the ADV7181C output. You can even process the scaling on the fly, you don't need to buffer more than a scanline (so that's 32 pixels * 24 bits only). By the way, is [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/278268/will-80-mhz-arm-cortex-mcu-handle-output-of-video-decoder-ycbcr-422) related? Of course, it is.

Comment: I think you might be able to do it with the μDMA subsystem, which is capable of transferring in one byte on every trigger of a GPIO pin. You can't do it with pure software interrupts, even at 12MHz. Once you've got it in memory you probably only have enough power for decimation/down-sampling, not interpolation.

Comment: I would assume the 'LLC' frequency was right at the bottom end of that range for PAL, but someone (by which I mean you) needs to do the maths to work out what the actual dot clock would be. Or get an eval board, scope and experiment.

Comment: @dim it's related; I recommended coming up with a diagram that specifies *what connects to what*; OP hasn't really done that, yet, but it's certainly an improvement in specificality over the last question.

Comment: I thought about DMA and RPi – the point is: more ram –> DMA can be used, no need to downscale online. However, GPIO pins have limit of 22 MHz, and there are problems with capacitance of helper wires: http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/03/benchmarking-raspberry-pi-gpio-speed/ It seems that this "110 MHz" is a serious number, I might not find way out after all, except for FPGA.